# Java.io.file constructor to deal with UNC file path

Tags: java, jar, unc

When I try to use the JAR file in the UNC path, I find I met a problem. The constructor of `java.io.file` will always convert a UNC file path to local path.

For example, I try

```
String dirStr = "file:\\\\dir1\dir2\file.jar!Myclass";
File ff = new File(dirStr);
System.out.println(ff.toString());
```

I'll get output like: `file:\dir1\dir2\file.jar!Myclass`. But what I expect to get is `file:\\dir1\dir2\file.jar!MyClass`.

I tried to add more slashes in the `dirStr`,  but it can't work. Because in the `java.io.file`, it'll call method to remove duplicated slashes.

And I try to use the `URI` to create the `ff`. But the output will be `\dir1\dir2\file.jar!Myclass`, which is not available to use JAR file successfully. I think the form of JAR must be start with the `file:` protocol to use parse  the string ending with `!` in above string `\dir1\dir2\file.jar!Myclass`.

Is there any way can `new File()` to get the pathname of `File`, i.e. `ff`, like `file:\\dir1\dir2\file.jar!MyClass`.

Comment: I think the `file:` prefix is usually used for local paths. A UNC path is not a local path. Try without the `file:` prefix, that is, `\\dir1\dir2\file.jar!MyClass`. You can also try with forward slashes, `//dir1/dir2/file.jar!MyClass`

Comment: Why do you think you have to supply a URL to a `File` constructor? You can't, and you don't have to. Unclear what you're really asking here.

Comment: Because I need to use the JAR file in the UNC path. When your java CLASSPATH include the remote UNC path, you will meet this problem. It will parse the JAR file like `dirStr`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your input dir String is UNC type, i think you should use Java's [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).

Example code:

```
URI uri = new URI(dirStr);
System.out.println(uri.toString());　// If you want to get the path as URI
File ff = new File(uri.getPath()); // If you want to access the file.
```

The other better way is using Path:

```
URI uri = new URI(dirStr);
Path path = Paths.get(uri); // Or directly Path path = Paths.get(dirStr);
File ff = path.toFile();  // << your file here
path.toUri();   // << your uri path here
```

Comment: I've tried this code, the `ff` will be like this `\\dir1\dir2\file.jar!MyClass` without `file:`.

Comment: So you just go `uri.toString()`.

Comment: Thanks @Minh. But here my point is not printing out the correct dirStr, but to assign the `file:\\dir1\dir2\file.jar!Myclass` to the `ff` object. So, the edited code can print correct UNC path, but the `ff` still can't get the correct string. Instead `ff` got the pathname string `\\dir1\dir2\file.jar!Myclass`, which is still lack of `file:`.

Comment: I don't know why you have to input into File constructor an URI like that. But you can use `Path` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor `File(String)` takes a path, not a URL. Remove the `file:` part and use two backslashes for every one in the actual filename, to satisfy the compiler's escaping rules. Or use the correct number of forward slashes.

Comment: In fact, I didn't use URL, but URI.

Comment: And if I remove the `file:`, it won't be able to find the JAR file. I guess it is due to there's one `!` after the string `.jar`.

Comment: If you must have `file:` you should not be using `File`. The two do not go together, as I have already stated.